# How can show item after Nth item in number list

Tags: php

I have array of numbers

```
$myArr = [0, 1, 2 ..... , 100];
```

I have step variable

```
$step = 3;
```

I want to show some text (for example "X") after every ($step) items:

> 0 1 2 **X** 3 4 5 **X** 6 7 8 **X** 9 10 11 **X** ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the X appears just before the multiple of `$step` appears. So, before printing the loop element `$i`, we need to check if it's a multiple of 3. Try this:

```
$myArr = range(0,100);
$step = 3;

foreach ($myArr as $i) {
    if ($i % $step == 0 && $i > 0) {
        echo 'X';
    }
    echo $i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, maybe it need to be count($myArr) in loop?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Or you could use `foreach` instead.

Comment: can you suggest - how can i check is it X or number - knowing the step value and number of position that I am checking?

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm to generate the desired string would be like this:

- Use a `for` loop to loop through the elements of the array.
- In each iteration, check if `$step` number of elements have been appended to the `$output` string or not.
- If `$step` number of elements have already been appended to the `$output` string, then append `X` to the `$output` string, otherwise append the current element of the array to the `$output` string.
- Finally after coming out of the loop, display the resultant `$output` string using `echo $output;`.

So your code should be like this:

```
$output = '';
$count = count($myArr);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i){
    if($i != 0 && $i % $step == 0) $output .= 'X ';
    $output .= $myArr[$i] . ' ';
}

// Display resultant $outout string
echo $output;
```

Here's the [**live demo**](https://eval.in/721622)

Comment: can you suggest - how can i check is it X or number - knowing the step value and number of position that I am checking?

Comment: @moonvader You can more clearly differentiate the step value and the number like this, [https://eval.in/721629](https://eval.in/721629).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example for actual array output, it can work with any type of array values with the same logic,

```
$num_arr = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);
$step = 3;
$count = 0;
$i = 0;
$final_arr = array();
foreach ( $num_arr as $num ){
    if( $i % $step  == 0 && $i > 0 ){
        $final_arr[$i+$count] = 'X';
        $final_arr[$i+$count+1] = $num;
        $count++;
    }
    else{
        $final_arr[$i+$count] = $num;
    }
    $i++;
}
print_r($final_arr);
```